# What is the maximum number of delegates a class can conform to? Swift 2

Tags: delegates, swift2

Currently a class of mine is conforming to 6 delegates, I feel that this is far from reaching the limit - if there is a limit. I am wondering if there is a limit to number of delegates a class can confirm to?

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt there is a limit and it rarely comes up as developers create classes to provide specific functionality, and no-one has a class that does everything.  I think with 6, you are probably doing too much in a single class.

Comment: @trojanfoe I agree with you. Thank you for the answer. I will revise the class and see what I can do. It is basically a tableView with 4 different custom cells. I use different delegates for each cell; I can combine the delegate into one. The other two delegates are UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: Well that seems fine; all delegates relate to the tableview.